# Different result from SAS/IML and R, in SVD decomposition

Tags: r, sas, translate, svd, sas-iml

shortly, I'm translating an R package into IML languageand I'm totally struggling myself with the SVD decomposition result between R and IML.

R code:

```
s <- svd(MAT) 
s$v
```

SAS/IML code:

```
call svd (U, D, V, MAT);
print V;
```

V is in both sides the matrix containing right singular vectors from the SVD decomposition, but here, please take a look at these results from R:

```
             [,1]         [,2]         [,3]        [,4]        [,5]         [,6]         [,7]
[1,] -2.625059e-02  0.029572211 -0.006491235 0.015622547  0.01553215 -0.003882378  0.007250290
[2,] -4.762146e-06 -0.030403155 -0.016635218 0.024949110 -0.01238686  0.001334805  0.041902431
[3,] -8.460010e-02  0.025365547  0.006657322 0.020129575 -0.02312842  0.038366880  0.054249177
[4,] -1.368302e-02  0.029621706  0.005462163 0.017887163  0.02605000 -0.002546119 -0.001913554
[5,] -3.326751e-02  0.003552646  0.003634580 0.065277891 -0.01218518 -0.026305833  0.029209961
[6,] -1.451836e-02  0.089992653 -0.012355758 0.009777273 -0.07790069 -0.044679172 -0.028174261
```

and these result from SAS/IML:

```
            COL1      COL2      COL3      COL4      COL5      COL6      COL7      COL8      COL9

 ROW1   0.0262506 -0.029572 -0.006491 0.0156225 0.0155322 -0.003882  -0.00725  0.040721 -0.000566
 ROW2   4.7621E-6 0.0304032 -0.016635 0.0249491 -0.012387 0.0013348 -0.041902 0.0225321 0.0070566
 ROW3   0.0846001 -0.025366 0.0066573 0.0201296 -0.023128 0.0383669 -0.054249 0.0305745 -0.041534
 ROW4    0.013683 -0.029622 0.0054622 0.0178872   0.02605 -0.002546 0.0019136 0.0168932 0.0229999
 ROW5   0.0332675 -0.003553 0.0036346 0.0652779 -0.012185 -0.026306  -0.02921 -0.029533 0.0145009
 ROW6   0.0145184 -0.089993 -0.012356 0.0097773 -0.077901 -0.044679 0.0281743 -0.025475 -0.036881
 ROW7   -0.012385 0.0295035 0.0051056   -0.0007 0.0025335 -0.009391 -0.045927 -0.054661 -0.029963
```

The values are the same as you can see, but their signs are sometimes the same and sometimes different. I can't find any reason why this is happening and this is totally driving me crazy.
Could someone give me a solution, or at least an hint or anything.
Any help will be appreciated, also if it won't solve this problem.

Many thanks.

EDIT: obviosly, results posted are only a portion of the total matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the SVD decomposition is not unique.

The singular vectors of M are the eigenvectors of M`M.  Eigenvectors are not unique. Even when the matrix is full rank, the eigenvectors are only defined up to a sign: If v is an eigenvector of the matrix A for eigenvalue lambda, then so is -v because
A*(-v) = -(Av) = -(lambda v) = lambda (-v).

Different SVD (and eigenvalue) algorithms can lead to different decompositions. As long as M = UDV`, the decomposition is valid.  The D matrix of singular values will be essentially the same across software packages, but the U and V matrices can be different.

Incidentally, if your matrix is not full rank, then even "uniqueness up to sign" breaks down. [The Wikipedia article on the SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Example) has an example of two very different SVDs for the same rank-deficient matrix.

Comment: great, thank you for the answer.
Now, is there a way to understand how SAS IML assign signs to values of singular vectors?

Comment: It doesn't "assign signs." The algorithm creates the U and V matrix and different algorithms might result in different U and V matrices.  The SAS/IML doc refers to Wilkinson and Reinsch (1971). The R doc says that R uses the LAPACK algorithm, which is FORTRAN code and works on complex matrices as well as real matrices.

Comment: Thank you very much again Rick, your help is really useful. Your blog is very inspiring and my "landmark" for IML